# delete & add a record to sql table while incrementing the date

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table with 364 rows/records each with a unique date. I want to be able to cut & copy the first record when that day has passed and then paste a new record with an incremented date to the bottom of the table... always maintaining a 364 record count.

The record being cut & copied contains several other columns of data and can be copied as is... nothing needs to be changed in those records.

Example:

```
Date
------------------------------------
2018-05-20... Other columns of data
2018-05-21... Other columns of data
2018-05-22... Other columns of data
2018-05-23... Other columns of data
2018-05-24... Other columns of data
2018-05-25... Other columns of data
2018-05-26... Other columns of data
......
2019-05-17... Other columns of data
2019-05-18... Other columns of data
```

In the above I would want the 2018-05-20 record to be cut & copied and then pasted as a new record incrementing the last record date by 1. So the pasted record would be 2019-05-19.

I realize my 364 records are one day shy of a year. I have a reason for doing so.

How would I write this stored procedure?

Comment: By the way... this stored procedure would run every 24 hours.

Comment: Do you have an ID column? Super easy to do this with MIN and Max

Comment: You don't need to delete or add something. Except the date looks like you have fixed data. Then don't even store a date, just store an int column ranging from 1 to 364. You can add the date column as a computed column.

Comment: You have a misconception that a relational table has any concept of "bottom". Just **update** the existing record to use the new date or, even better, set all your records to use a generic year value and avoid the need for any moving parts in this system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to insert the line with the MIN(DATE) and increment it by MAX(DATE) + 1. Then Delete the Min Date

```
create table #temp (dates date, col1 varchar(20),col2 varchar(20))

insert into #temp 
Values ('12-01-2018', '10','11')
,('12-03-2018', '10','12')
,('12-04-2018', '10','13')
,('12-05-2018', '10','14')
,('12-06-2018', '10','15')
,('12-08-2018', '10','16')


INSERT INTO #Temp (dates,col1,col2)
SElect DATEADD(dd,1,(select max(dates) from #temp))
        ,col1,col2
from #temp t
where dates = (select min(dates) from #temp)

delete 
from #temp
where dates = (select min(dates) from #temp)
```

Alternatively you could just do an update.

```
Update #temp
Set dates = DATEADD(dd,1,(select max(dates) from #temp))
where dates = (select min(dates) from #temp)
```